# How do I safely include php files that may have whitespace after closing php tags?

Tags: php

I just spent an hour tracking down a bug in a php script that creates an XML file which would not parse because there was a blank line at the end of it (probably just a cut-and-paste bug), I would prefer that my script not be susceptible to these kinds of errors in included file in the future.

Is there any way to ensure that using the include or require_once functions doesn't result in any output?  Unless I'm using one as a template, I'm usually using these functions so I can include functions in other PHP files and have no expectation that they have any HTML embedded in them.

Comment: `ob_start(); include 'file.php'; ob_end_clean();`

Comment: 10000000 questions on this site, I search for ob_start and find thousands of hits.  but I can't find the question to go with it.  Thanks,  I'll delete this question though!

Comment: why do you delete it?

Comment: @const mainly to avoid the hassle of having it closed as a duplicate.  although I can't find the duplicate very easy.

Comment: I'm not too sure but would removing the closing PHP tag fix your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question doesn't have any value. Wait to see then delete it.

Comment: @uom, I tried that, I think the whitespace may have been before the <?XML, and it wasn't the old "Headers Already Sent, Doofus"  problem.

Comment: @Const OK, no problem for me to leave it.

Comment: I will compose an answer. If you get downvotes then it should be deleted. I can't find a duplicate question like this.

Comment: Just throwing out ideas here without really thinking - how about write a script that trims all PHP files and removes leading and trailing spaces, new lines, etc.?

Comment: @uom, I could do that as a git-hook or something, but I think the ob_start nails it.  I'd imagine there could be legitimate reasons to put stuff I want to ignore in scripts that I want to use too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start output buffering capture, then include the file then discard any outputted content:

```
ob_start(); 
include 'file.php'; 
ob_end_clean();
```